# How do I make IE6 respect the class attribute?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, class, internet-explorer-6

Long time reader, first time poster asks:

After many weeks of google and forum trawling, I am still at a loss. I have a series of nested divs, some with ids, some with classes, and some with ids and classes.

It's XHTML strict, and validates.
Original code http://www.drewsonne.com/melonstack/?topic=brisbane

eg.

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="rEntry" id="r1">
    <a href="http://www.brisbane.com">City of Brisbane</a><br>
    <span id="rSum1" class="rSum">This is a website summary</span>
  </div>
  <div class="rEntry" id="r2">
    <a href="http://www.brisbane.gov.au">City of Brisbane</a><br>
    <span id="rSum2" class="rSum">This is a website summary as well</span>
  </div>
    ... et cetera ...
</div>
```

For the purposes of testing, my CSS currently looks like this

```
.rEntry{
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
}
```

For the life of me, I can not get this style to work at all in IE6. If I change to #r1, #r2, or div the style is applied to the appropriate elements, but neither div.rEntry nor .rEntry will make the style stick. Does anyone know where I have gone wrong?

DJS.

Comment: Please start ignoring IE6! If you don't it will live forever... Tell them to upgrade... just tell them to at least upgrade to ie 7 or 8..

Comment: Thomaschaaf: IE6 is still at around 15 % usage share. Depending on the site shutting out 15 % pf users is probably a really bad idea. Drew: Why are you using the ID "rsum1" twice? IDs have to be unique throughout the document.

Comment: IE6 usage varies greatly depending on the site. On Stackoverflow for example, I'd be surprised if Firefox usage was less than 50% and IE6 usage was more than 1%. On Ebay it might be as much as 10% or more IE6. Overall though I think IE6 is around 10% not 15% though but I do agree that supporting it is generally still an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, looking at the HTML at your provided link, I don't see any divs with the rEntry class.  Then I realized, they were being generated dynamically.  That reminded me that for IE6, when adding CSS classes through the DOM, you have to use the className property, not class.  In other words, the IE6 DOM is not seeing that the divs are of class rEntry at all.

How are those divs being generated?  If it's through your own code, you may want to try modifying the class AND className properties of your elements.

**edit**: It looks like it's in scripts/REsultsList.js.  Try changing the line that says:

```
entry_div_element.setAttribute('class', 'rEntry');
```

to:

```
entry_div_element.setAttribute('class', 'rEntry');
entry_div_element.className = 'rEntry';
```

Comment: This is the right reason. There's a neat workaround for the setAttribute method you're using at http://delete.me.uk/2004/09/ieproto.html

Comment: ... you... are freaking awesome. I've been trying to work that out for the last month. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

I have three pieces of advice:

1. Use a [reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) (there are several of these around);
2. [Use a DOCTYPE declaration](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/), if you aren't already, to force IE into standards-compliant mode (well, as standards compliant as IE can be) instead of quirks mode. I usually use HTML 4.01 transitional for this but if you comply with strict, even better;
3. Qualify your styles with the element name.

For example:

```
div.rEntry {
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
}
```

The more specific a style is, the greater its importance in CSS for determining which one applies. You can see if thats the issue by testing it with `!important`:

```
div.rEntry{
    padding:10px !important;
    margin:10px !important;
}
```

If that fixes the issue then you've got other CSS that is taking precedence. I suspect this is the issue as `#id` selectors have a higher precedence than `.class` selectors, which is the behaviour you're seeing.

**Note:** I don't recommend using `!important` as a general rule, just to find issues with CSS precedence. Once identified, it's generally best to fix them the "right" way.

Comment: Thank you for your response cletus!

Following your advice, there is a reset css, the page has a doctype with xhtml strict, application/xhtml+xml headers, and just to clarify, those 4 lines are the *only* CSS applied to the document at the moment (aside from the reset now applied). Unfortunately IE6 is still not moving my divs an inch.

Comment: ...and the styles are fully qualified width div.rEntry { ... }

Answer (score 0):

I just went to the "original code" link, and your CSS reads:

```
div.rEntry{
    margin:10px !important;
}   padding:10px !important;
```

It looks like your padding style is outside of the the bracket.  Are you certain this isn't all just due to a typo?

Comment: goddamit... thank you, 'tis back outside the bracket now... unfortunatly I am not so lucky, and those divs are still stuck. Have had to remove the application/xhtml+xml header, as IE6 tried to download the page.

Comment: you need to serve IE6 a text/html content-type header and application/xhtml+xml to the non-retarded browsers. the easiest way is to check the 'accept' client header and do a mod-rewrite.